# Combine multiple field input into single value in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Here, I would like to combine two input fields, how can I combine the `date_start` and my `time` into single value in laravel. (my field type : datetime)

Here is my script for view:

```
<div class="form-group date" style="float: left;">
    <label for="">Date</label>
    <input class="form-control tanggal" id="date" name="date_start"  
           placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" required />
</div>

<div class="form-group time" style="float: right;">
    <label for="">Time</label>
    <input type="time" name="time" placeholder="what time" 
           class="form-control" id="time" />
</div>
```

And this is my controller :

```html
$a['date_start'] = Session::get('date_start').  Session::get('time');
```

I have been try to running it, and i get result array like this,

```
Array ( [date_start] => 2016-08-1001:00 )
```

I think its right but in my database its still `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

what improvements do i have to make to the code to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already posted

> I think its right but in my database its still 0000-00-00 00:00:00

And your given input is 0000-00-0000:00 which is quite different.

You could use Carbon to make this a little bit more easy and ensure the date is correctly parsed.

```
$dateString = Session::get('date_start') . ' ' . Session::get('time') . ':00';
$date = new \Carbon\Carbon($dateString); // optional second parameter for timezone
```

Refer to http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ 
Carbon is available out of the box in Laravel. You can also add

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

at the very top to skip writing \Carbon\Carbon every time.

Comment: ahh,, i see i need to add space in the session now. btw its work thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you're trying to read the posted form values using `Session#get` which retrieves data from the session as opposed to `Request#input` which retrieves data from the form itself.

To retrieve form input values, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input:

For example:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function postMethodName(Request $request)
    {
        $a = [];

        $date_start = $request->input('date_start');
        $time = $request->input('time');

        // TODO: Add validation, sanitize, etc.
        $combined = sprintf('%s %s', $date_start, $time);

        $a['date_start'] = $combined; // new Carbon($combined);
    }
}
```