# Handle datetime field when submit form in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In my blade file, I have a form with a datetime dropdown to select like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.send-single') }}">
    @csrf
    <div>
        <label>Hours:</label>
        <select name="hour">
            @for ($i=0; $i<=23; $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>

        <select name="minute">
            @for ($i=0; $i<=59; $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>

        <label>Date:</label>
        <select name="day">
            @for ($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>

        <select name="month">
            @for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>

        <select name="year">
            @for ($i=2021; $i<=2030; $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I select date and time, then I submit the form and handle it in controller like this to get the datetime in Y-m-d H:i:s format:

```
$param = $request->except('_token');

$time = $param['year'].'-'.$param['month'].'-'.$param['day].' '.$param['hour'].':'.$param['minute].':00';
```

I think this code is not clean. Anyway for me to do this more clean? Something like format datetime to Y-m-d H:i:s in blade before and then submit to controller?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it necessary a field for each part of date (year, month, day, hour and minute)? It is more elegant to add a field with a date mask

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but to save yourself some hassle in the future, change your year for loop to `@for ($i=date('y'); $i<=date('y')+9; $i++)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are choosing to use dropdown input fields for your dates, if you can switch and there isn't some unknown reason that I am not currently aware of I would use either of the following:

- `<input type="date" />`
  https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_type_date.asp

Combined With:

- `<input type="time" />`
  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_time.asp

You may also try using the datetime-local input field, as this field type contains both the time and date, but this type is not very well supported for backwards compatibility.

- `<input type="datetime-local" />`
  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_datetime-local.asp

You can then capture the fields in the controller the same way you do any other field, and if you choose to use date and time field types in combination you can do something like the following:

```
$request->input( 'date_field' ) . ' ' . $request->input( 'time_field' )
```

I would not recommend this though, you should instead pre format the field in the model before the save.

You can do this using accessors and mutators, see:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Replace your form with this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.send-single') }}">
    @csrf

    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <label id="date-input-label">Date&#58;</label>
            <input name="date_field" type="date" min="2021-01-01" max="2030-12-31" aria-labelledby="date-input-label" />
            <input name="time_field" type="time" aria-labelledby="date-input-label" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then use a mutator to combine the fields or if you choose, you can combine them in the controller.

If you do choose to combine the fields in the controller you can use something like Carbon to ensure it is compatible.

See another Stack Overflow post:

[Combine multiple field input into single value in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863640/combine-multiple-field-input-into-single-value-in-laravel)

Carbon:

https://carbon.nesbot.com/

Comment: FYI `datetime-local` fields are still [not supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=datetime-local) in Firefox.